# Where are the Call History and Telegram secret chats stored?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, sms, telegram

I am working on the BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Phone and I am interested in finding out where the Phone Call history is stored. On a similar post I saw that the SMS are stored in this directory `~/.local/share/history-service/`  but there I can't seem to find anything on Call History.

As for the Telegram secret chats, I am curious to see where they are stored on the file system and if they will still be accessible there after deletion from the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call history is stored in `~/.local/share/history-service/history.sqlite` which you can edit with the `sqlite3` tool. See the table `voice_events`

I was able to successfully truncate my call history using a query to discard entries by date. Over time, the phone app on my BQ 4.5 had become very slow to respond. Having truncated the call history, the speed has improved a lot.

After truncating, I used the compact database option in the sqlite3 tool which shrunk the database size.

Answer (score 1):

As for Telegram, it creates a directory in `/userdata/user-data/phablet/.config/com.ubuntu.telegram/` named with the phone number of the other contact.

It's also interesting to know that even regular chats that are not stored on the device can be found in the cache in `/home/phablet/.cache/com.ubuntu.telegram/` in a directory with the user's phone number and inside a database file called `telegram.sqlite`

Still don't know about the call history logs, though.